# jQuery datepicker showing months and year combos in one row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to let user select year and month in both combo boxes. The issue is they are showed one under the other instead of one beside each other.

I want this:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Do you explicitly set the widths of the two `<select>` elements? Please add your CSS file(s).

Comment: increase the width... :)

Comment: What you want is the default behaviour of datepicker. What you are getting is due to some css settings. Somewhere the widths of select elements are being overridden

Comment: I make a theme using themeroller.

Comment: did you change anything in the theme css files?

Comment: I think the input width is overridden by some other css and due to which its width is increased. Check in firebug.

Comment: I've found it @jensgram and Abhilash thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved changing this css class form jquery-ui.css

```
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year { width: 30%;}
```

30% ensures in my case that both selects will be showed in one row. I used IE developer tools to find the css class:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way of changing the width no matter what the CSS says is:

1. Find the js file that has datapicker (usually jquery.ui.datepicker.js)
2. Find `var origyearshtml,
   numMonths = this._getNumberOfMonths(inst) ...`
3. Just under that or same line you'll notice `width=17`;
4. Change that to your preferred width.

This is the only solution that worked for me when using multiple months.